# C# Technology Options for Storing/Managing Calculations Remotely

Tags: c#, wcf

Trying to figure out what options I have available to have a program running locally get its calculations or results of the calculations from a remote source.

**Problem:**
I have a data acquisition application that reads a lot of instruments and collects data while testing equipment.  This data than goes through various forms of aggregation (min,max,average,etc) and than several calculations are applied to it and the result is saved to a database.  This process happens several times during a test.  This application runs on a machine dedicated to perform this test, but users outside of the test also need to perform the same calculations for experimentation, data analysis etc etc.

In the past, our two applications, (one with the equipment and the one with the users) would get updated every time a calculation changed and then deployed everywhere.  This is a pain.

**Question:**
I'm looking for possible options to solve this problem.

What I've found so far.

**1).  WCF.**

Like:
Only have to update the server and both the programs can now take advantage of the new calculation.

Concern:
The DataContract would contain several classes that would have to be passed to the function(s).  ( Total Size of "data" could range from 1 MB to 1 GB depending on the situation).  Not sure if the amount of data is an actual problem at this time.

**2).  Store compiled DLLs and download/load them.**
Query the server for a class library.  Download it.  Load it into memory and use the calculations.

Like:
Do not have to pass a lot of data back and forth.

Concern:
DLL that now resides on each and every computer. People may not be forced to update to the correct version which may cause problems.  DLL on the local persons computer may pose a security risk.

Comment: Additional Info:   There are 1 to 2 users of the calculations while running the application to test the equipment.  Outside of the testing there is around say 10 to 20 users majority of which only look at the results of the calculations.  (Essentially querying a database).  Of that group there is a small subset that currently has the ability to recalculate results.  I don't know how often this is performed by the group but with any users if you take away something they can currently do they tend to fight it even though in practice they likely never use the feature...

Comment: This entire processes than is repeated another 25 times.  IE) I have around 25 test systems that are all isolated from each other but we try to keep the software systems the same to make supporting the tools easier.  I am not concerned with bogging down the server as each system has their own server.  I'm more concerned with the amount of data being passed through the network and the general responsiveness of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few options we found that sending data back and forth was too cumbersome.  Instead we chose to load a DLL dynamically with all the calculations we require and use a set of interfaces to define the behaviour.

What I did learn and found was neat is that I can store the DLL in the database and load it directly into memory without having to copy it to the hard drive first thus providing an added layer of protection.  Using SQL and FILESTREAM.  It also provides a sort of version control in that I can choose which version of the DLL to load from the database and calculate/recalculate the various values.

```
 // Read in File
 using (SqlFileStream fileStream = new SqlFileStream(path, transaction, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
 {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
      int bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

       // Load Assembly
       Assembly DLL = Assembly.Load(buffer);

       Type myInterfaceType = DLL.GetType("MyNamespace.MyClass");

       // Get access to the root interface
       IMyInterface myClass = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(myInterfaceType);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a pretty tricky question and I think there are quite a number of ways you could try solve it. Here are a few ideas that may get you started

1. Use Akka.Net and take a look at [Akka.Remote](http://getakka.net/docs/remoting/deployment) which may be able to solve your remote deploy issue. But I'm not sure that this will fit with what you need if you have users deciding to join the cluster ad-hoc rather than having a fixed set of places to distribute calculations?
2. If the calculations are simple mathematical formulas you could store them as a set of rules and download the formulas. I.e. taking more of a rules engine approach. See perhaps [C# expression trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx)
3. Browser based solution. This clearly wins from a ease of remote deployment point of view. There are many options if you don't want to use JavaScript, e.g. PureScript, F# (Fable), ClojureScipt, ELM and possibly even C# with JSIL/Bridge. Moving from desktop to web is quite a big shift though so make sure you know what you are in for :)

Comment: Also I think a lot depends on how much you really want local vs remote. What I'm not clear on from your question is what needs to be calculated local vs remote. Does each user only need the aggregated data? If so do they really need to do any calculation or just view the results? If there are remote calcs then the WCF/service based approach means your server is going to be doing a lot of work and transmitting a lot of data. At some point you need to factor that in too

Comment: Thanks for the information so far.  I'm going to have to do a bit more reading on Akka.Remote.  (Its looks a lot like an actor framework which I'm familiar with in LabVIEW).  C# Expression trees will not work because the calculations are too complex.  Regression, lookup tables, 4th order polynomials, etc.  (I'm calculating performance for Turbine Engines).  I've considered a browser solution but the team isn't comfortable at this time moving that direction.

Comment: Yeah, moving to browser based is a large step :) Another option is to look at a grid / mesh computing solution. Again it really depends on if you can/want to rely on having the clients available or if they join ad-hoc to view results only. Anyway good luck, sounds like and interesting problem.